# HTML | Como cambiar el titulo de la pestaña del Navegador?

Tags: html, diseño

Tengo una pregunta que puede parecer simple, pero no encuentro la solucion y lo he intentado.

Estoy utilizando *AngularJS* para una página y cuando estoy en otra página quiere que el título de la pestaña tambien cambie, por que me sale el titulo de todas las páginas así como puse en el `Index`, y quiero que cambie, que no solo se vea el título como puse en el `index.html`, sino que cada página tenga un título diferente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

Define el controller en el `<html>`.

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="titleCtrl">
  <head>
  <title>{{ Page.title() }}</title>
  ...
```

Comment: Y podes pasar tu codigo js y el contenido de Page.title?

Answer (score 3):

A estos cambios podrias hacerlo con javascript puro

```
window.document.title = 'Tu titulo';
```

Esto no ademas podrías modificarlo cuando quieras, de hecho si tienes formularios internos, acompañas el cambio de titulo con este evento..

Comment: no me funciono amigo, o no seguro no estoy llamando bien

Answer (score 2):

Usa el servicio **Title**

> src/app/app.component.ts (class)

```
export class AppComponent {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
  }
}
```

> src/main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

> src/app//app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```